# RegSvcs.exe registering the same dll twice

Tags: .net, com+, component-services

Let's say I have the same .net managed dll (same version, same code) in two diferent bin folders of two diferent exe applications. If I register the two dlls into COM+ using RegSvcs.exe /appname:app1 pathtodll1/example.dll and RegSvcs.exe /appname:app2 pathtodll2/example.dll. Can I assume one exe will allways run the app1 com+ and the other exe will run the app2 com+?

I mean I don't see how the exe client application, a managed application by the way, resolve which COM+ application it should run when asking for the dll if I am able to change the appname at registering time...

<del>Do they use the registry CodeBase property to figure out the appname?</del>

Edit:
It seems I cannot register the second time.
Then I have another question...
When app2 runs and ask for example.dll services which dll is really uploaded the one next to app1.exe or the one from app2.exe? Do I really need to copy example.dll in app2 bin folder?

If I add a third non com+ dll (second.dll) in the mix, that is referenced by the two exe's and by the example.dll which second.dll will get loaded in the app2.exe app domain?

Answer (score 0):

It seems which dll the loader choose has nothing to do with component services. COM+ from a .net perspective is just a settings store. So when a given dll is loaded as usual in the app domain, it asks the COM+ store if itself (ie a dll with the same version and interface) exists there. If it exists then it reads its COM+ settings. If it doesn't I think it tries to autoregister itself in COM+ (using default COM+ settings).